# Looking for someone to render a quality rendition of a song I wrote

Tags: guitar, recording, beginner

What resources are there on the internet for someone who

- Writes music
- Is intermediate at best in guitar-playing ability
- Wants someone with above-average to top playing ability to learn a song they have written, record it, and make it available for the writer to download

---

Provided by the writer (at least):

- Tablature of the piece
- A recording by the author, giving their best approximate representation of how the piece should sound

---

Looking for both free(1) and paid(2) sites.

---

**BONUS:**
I'd assume that if these resources exist, some of these would do the same for voice etc., or others would do the same for voice etc.

<sub>Probably seachable on google, but I couldn't find the right search words?</sub>

Comment: Try visiting both recording and rehearsal studios. Guys there will have an inkling as to who on their books may be interested, and put you in touch.

Comment: Lots of resources. I'd have a go myself if I liked the song and the fee. One possible site you might try is 'upwork' where folks post jobs of this kind.

Comment: @PeterJ What kind of fee is normal for you compared to Studios? If you don't want to answer fully, I'll understand. BTW this is finger pick-style acoustic.

Comment: I was joking really. These jobs are usually so time-consuming that a sensible fee is impossible. But I would consider having a go if you can let me hear the song or see the score.We cannot sort this out here though. Do you have a blog or other address?

Answer (score 2):

I would look for music services in either [UpWork](https://www.upwork.com/freelance-jobs/music/) or [Fiverr](https://www.fiverr.com/search/gigs?query=music&source=top-bar&search_in=everywhere&search-autocomplete-original-term=music)

Professionals charge differently according to their skill.

Expecting a stranger of "above-average to top playing ability" to do work for you is unreasonable, unless that person is a friend.

I would browse one of the sites suggested above to find somebody who is willing to do the work for you and agree on a price. Good luck! If you're the sharing type, upload it to Soundcloud and post a link somewhere so we can hear it.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re willing to wade into it and sift the wheat from the chaff, Craigslist musicians community may be a place to ask around.